# Focal-loss pip installation screwed my conda env for supported GPU tensorflow installation

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

When I did  pip install focal-loss  <2022-04-20 Wed 10:00>
I got this:
Installing collected packages: tensorboard-data-server, tf-estimator-nightly, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, tensorboard, libclang, keras, flatbuffers, tensorflow, focal-loss
Attempting uninstall: tensorboard
Found existing installation: tensorboard 2.2.2
Uninstalling tensorboard-2.2.2:
Successfully uninstalled tensorboard-2.2.2

*ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:\Ahmed\code\enviorment\conda_env_dir\tf220\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\experimental\microfrontend\python\ops\_audio_microfrontend_op.so'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.*

Now pip list shows tensorboard 2.8

spyder                            5.2.2
spyder-kernels                    2.2.1
tensorboard                       2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server           0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit            1.8.0
tensorflow-gpu                    2.2.0
tensorflow-gpu-estimator          2.2.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem      0.24.0

- after I run

  - pip install focal-loss --user*

    I end up with unwantedly installed tensorflow 2.8:

    Installing collected packages: tensorflow, focal-loss
    WARNING: The scripts estimator_ckpt_converter.exe, import_pb_to_tensorboard.exe, saved_model_cli.exe, tensorboard.exe, tf_upgrade_v2.exe, tflite_convert.exe, toco.exe and toco_from_protos.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\ahmed\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
    Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
    Successfully installed focal-loss-0.0.7 tensorflow-2.8.0
- Now I got tensorflow-2.8.0 installed in my conda env originaly created for gpu supported tensorflow-2.2.0
- I tried to remove it using

  - pip uninstall tensorflow-2.8.0*

Now I got
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'

- I restarted the conda session and my script craches on this error:
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.util.dispatch' has no attribute 'add_fallback_dispatch_list'
- As a last trial I tested the rollback to previous configuration of my conda env using
  conda list --revisions command,
  but I the proposed revisons were outdated and did not show much details about current and prvious pip packages installation that I hoped to get back to. So I choose the one befor the last. After running my script, my code still crashes into this error:
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.util.dispatch' has no attribute 'add_fallback_dispatch_list' for which I did not find solution on the net.

I wander why for the [focal-loss package](https://pypi.org/project/focal-loss/) the pip packages manager do not show prerequests and warnings about incompatible/compatible tensorflow versions and (y/n) options to accept/deny insatallation.

Is there pip command to rollback to previous configuration inside coonda env

Answer (score 0):

There is some version mismatch problem among packages in your system. You can try again using:

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu   # which will install latest tensorflow version in your environment.
```

and then install your required package (focal-loss) as below:

```
 !pip install focal-loss   # this will install latest focal-loss=0.0.7
```

Comment: I am not interested in upgrading. Besides upgrading will install the latest version of tensorflow-gpu, wich will not be supported by nvidia drivers, cuda toolkit and cudnn installations that have been already made in my windows machine for tf 2.2.0 gpu version.

Comment: You can try with a lower version of [focal-loss](https://pypi.org/project/focal-loss/#history) to install in TF 2.2 - `pip install focal-loss==0.0.2`.

Though the latest `focal-loss==0.0.7` also supports TF >=2.2 but this version may try to upgrade the existing libraries version.

Comment: I did not find the info which focal-loss version is supported by tf-gpu-2.2.0, so I did not try pip install focal-loss==0.0.2